# meteorjs (CollectionFS) read the files source

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteor-collections

I am using CollectionFS for my meteorjs Application and trying to upload a file and then read the source to do other stuff.

The holw list I want to do is the following:

1. Upload the file
2. Read out the source
3. Depends on the content I will delete or will not delete the file

Step 1 and 3 are no problem - but the second step I don't understand how to do. There are some Callbacks where I can "access" the file (like build a readStream and so on) but I do not understand how to use this to read out the hole source code.

In my case I upload a CSV file and after uploading it I want to analyse the content - but how to solve step 2 with using CollectionFS ?

Comment: you want to access the data before or after is inserted?? or just want to access them? no matter if is after or before the file was inserted?

Comment: How did you manage to do it? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Hey Binary Brain: You can do this with the transformRead stream (in CollectionFS Guide examples are given). If I find my old script I will post it.